# Dialogflow - Google Assistant: @sys.any entity not catching sequence of digits

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created an Intent, which outputs a context with a given parameter name, let's say `$myParam`. The goal of this Intent is to catch a long sequence of numbers. I know there is a `@sys.number-sequence` entity but, I'm using **Italian** language and this kind of entity is not available. There is only `@sys.number`, but the numbers I'm expecting from the user are out of its range.

Under these restrictions, I choosed `@sys.any` as entity for my parameter `$myParam`.

**Problem**

When the user enters the digits, in a real device, the Assistant might add some white spaces between them (while the user says them).

When the Assistant gets the sequence `111 222`, the Intent is triggered and everything goes OK.

But, when the Assistant gets the sequence `111222` (note the missing of the white space) it doesn't work.

I was expecting that `@sys.any` entity catches all inputs but it doesn't look like that.

Do you know how to deal with this case?

My goal is to trigger the intent even when the Assistant catches the sequence of digits without space between, before or after the sequence.

Image:

https://ibb.co/ngBzGtx

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Intent that isn't working?

Comment: @Prisoner Just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem in the recent days and it was really annoying. Suddenly, for some reason that I don't know, Assistant's `@sys.any` entity was not working any more for catching numbers.

My use case is pretty much as yours, I have a parent Intent where I ask the user to enter a code (10-15 digits), and I have created a follow-up intent to handle user's input. I'm using a language *different from english*, and the **only** entity that the system offers for catching long numbers is `@sys.any`.

But it stopped working! I came around to find a way to somehow force the assistant to enter in a specific intent, because not only the follow-up intent isn't triggered now, but the fallback intent either. Assistant just holds on in the parent intent and goes to crash.

After I spent some hours finding nothing useful, I tried this trick which worked for me. 
When creating an intent, by default it has a **Normal** priority. Changing the priority of the follow-up intent, that I want to be triggered with the parameter of entity type `@sys.any` holding the user's input, to **High** solved my issue. Now it's working correctly as it used to work before.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `@sys.any` entity generally shouldn't be used to cover everything in the phrase. For cases like this, you should be able to use a Fallback Intent and then process the entire input from the user.

Comment: This Intent is a follow-up. In the parent Intent I ask the user to say the sequence of digits and I expect this followup intent to be triggered and the input to be in `$myParam`. When the user says a random string, e sequence of digits with space between, or whatever combination it works as it should. The only problem is when the input only contains digits. As far as I remember this is a recent days problem because it used to work until 2 or 3 days ago. Maybe Assistant has been updated in these days and its libraries have changed.

Comment: I also added a Fallback Intent in the parent Intent but still not working. When I enter the digits without white space, none of the child Intents (the custom one which I refered in the question and the Fallback one) is triggered.